# C# overload methods behavior with interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, overloading, overload-resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# 4: conflicting overloaded methods with optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674417/c-4-conflicting-overloaded-methods-with-optional-parameters)

I just have one small research and created next code.

> ```
> namespace Test {
> class Program
> {
>     public interface ITestA
>     {
>         void MethodA(int a, int b);
>     }
>
>     public class TestAClass : ITestA
>     {
>         public void MethodA(int a, int b)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("MethodA with param");
>         }
>
>         public void MethodA(int a, int b, bool logic = true)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("MethodA logic with param");
>         }
>     }
>
>     public interface ITestB
>     {
>         void MethodA(int a, int b, bool logic = true);
>     }
>
>     public class TestBClass : ITestB
>     {
>         public void MethodA(int a, int b)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("MethodB with param");
>         }         
>
>         public void MethodA(int a, int b, bool logic = true)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("MethodB logic with param");
>         }
>     }
>
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         var testA = new TestAClass();
>         testA.MethodA(1, 1);            
>         var testB = new TestBClass();
>         testB.MethodA(1, 1);   
>     }
> } }
> ```

I have a question why compiler always choose short method with 2 parameters. And of course all this work by the same way and without Interface.

Thanks

Comment: So if it works the same way with and without the interface, why show the interface in your question? The idea is to use the *minimal* amount of code needed to reproduce the behavior. That keeps us focused on the actual question, rather than irrelevant details.

Comment: Also, this is most certainly **not** operator overloading, but rather *method* overloading, a completely different thing.

Comment: And the main issue is with optional parameters, not interfaces.

Comment: If these sorts of topics interest you, you might want to check out my blog this week. I'm running a series on how interfaces and optional argument declarations work in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This boils down to how the compiler treats **named and optional parameters**.
Check out [this article at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) for more information, especially the paragraph *Overload Resolution*.

> If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a candidate that **does not have optional parameters** for which arguments were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer parameters.

This is why in your case the compiler chooses the method without any optional parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Because compiler finds a method that correspond perfectly to calling method and use that.
Compiler searches for other suitable methods if first way fails...