# Migration To NET6

Tags: identityserver4, .net-6.0

I tried to migrate my ASP CORE project to NET6
My project uses next packages

IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation - 3.0.1

IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection - 4.0.1

IdentityModel - 5.2.0

The build of project is success.
But when I run application I get error

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryEndpoint IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryEndpoint.ParseUrl(System.String)'.
IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions.ConfigureJwtBearer(JwtBearerOptions jwtOptions)
IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.ConfigureInternalOptions.Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory<TOptions>.Create(string name)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor<TOptions>+<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Get>b__0()
```

Anybody had this issue ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I investigated this problem and found cause.
I used IdentityModel V 4,2,2 before update.
When I update my project to NET 6, IdentityModel was upgrated to version 5.2.0.
The difference between IdentityModel V 4,2,2 and IdentityModel version 5.2.0 was in signature method.

```
public static DiscoveryEndpoint ParseUrl(string input, string path = null) version 5,2,0
public static DiscoveryEndpoint ParseUrl(string input) version 4,2,2
```

So we see that in new version default parameter was added.
But this method is called by method from IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation package. And this package was not compiled to call updated ParseUrl function.

See this topic about this problem [c# method with default parameter value does not generate overload without parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184423/c-sharp-method-with-default-parameter-value-does-not-generate-overload-without-p)

Comment: Did you end up solving the issue? If so, how?

Comment: @JonHalliday YEs. I solved. I did not update IdentityModel package from 4.2.2. Just stayed old version

Comment: Yeah, I had this same thing as well. Have to roll back IdentityModel to 4.6 (the latest 4.x.x) to get it working

Comment: So, for now, the only solution is to use a version lower than 5, right? I'm thinking why they didn't fix that problem, the IdentityModel lib is now in the version 6 and the error is still ocurring

Comment: i was able to use `IdentityModel 5.1.1`. it seems `5.2.0` is the one that stops supporting `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation 3.0.1`

Comment: In my case, I upgrade to asp net core 7.0, but IdentityModel >=5.2.0 is not working.

Answer (score 17):

Roman's answer is correct, we can **fix it by doing the IdentityModel downgrade**, but another way to fix that issue is by replacing the **IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation** by **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer**, and we can change a little bit the token validation, using **IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation** we were doing the validation like this:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(
        options =>
        {
            options.Authority = configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
            options.ApiName = configuration["Authentication:ApiName"];
        });
```

Now we can do the token validation using the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer** like that:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new List<string>() { configuration["Authentication:ApiName"] };
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation library is deprecated, and hence does not have a version, which is compiled against IdentityModel version 5.2.0.

You should use the new approach described in https://leastprivilege.com/2020/07/06/flexible-access-token-validation-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try with **IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection 6.2.0**. It's working for me when I migrate IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation to .Net 6 Web API.

Configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OAuth2IntrospectionDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddOAuth2Introspection(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://base_address_of_token_service";

        options.ClientId = "client_id_for_introspection_endpoint";
        options.ClientSecret = "client_secret_for_introspection_endpoint";
    })
```

Please find more details at https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection

Nuget : https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection/6.2.0?_src=template