# Overloading a function that has default arguments

Tags: c++, overloading, default-parameters, default-arguments

In C++, if I overload a function like the following

```
void foo(int bar);
void foo(int bar, float baz = 0);
```

And then I call it

```
foo(1);
```

Which foo would be called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conflicting overloaded methods with optional parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674417/conflicting-overloaded-methods-with-optional-parameters)

Comment: This is invalid. What is your reason for trying to do this? We can possibly find an alternative solution.

Comment: I was just curious about it actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried, and it won't compile as David Haim said in his comment to my question.

Answer (score -2):

Why would you even need the first? Seems redundant. The first one will be hit. This is a duplicate. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674417/conflicting-overloaded-methods-with-optional-parameters) for answer.

Comment: Why would I need the first, you mean?

Comment: Yes, I meant the first - edited for clarity. The second would cover both cases. But still, a dupe question. See my link for more explanation: "If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer parameters."

Comment: The "answer" you pointed to is about C# and OP asked about C++ which has different rules of overload resolution.

Comment: It is still considered ambiguous. From [learnCPP.com](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters/) "However, it is important to note that default parameters do NOT count towards the parameters that make the function unique. Consequently, the following is not allowed:

void printValues(int x);
void printValues(int x, int y=20);
If the caller were to call printValues(10), the compiler would not be able to disambiguate whether the user wanted printValues(int) or printValues(int, 20) with the default value."